# Ignition switch issue

Tags: electrical, ford, ignition-switch, f-350

2003 Ford F350 super duty.  Ignition switch failed:  turns clockwise without clicks, engine will not start, and electrical system (all except starter solenoid) remain hot even with ignition switch off, or even with ignition switch totally removed from column.  Replaced ignition switch without any effect.  Could it be a bad ignition relay?  In what fuse/relay box is the ignition relay?

Thanks.

Comment: If there isn’t a power distribution box under the hood it’s probably located in the smart junction box. Probably in the right side kick panel.